# how do i sync my windows ce 6.0 device with my windows 7 pc

Tags: windows-ce, activesync

I have a PDA device running Windows Embedded CE 6.0, which I need to sync using WMDC (Windows Mobile Device Center) as my system operates on Windows 7 professional. However the WMDC does not detect the device as an active connection in spite of the device being available as a usb mass storage device on the Win 7 system. My query is whether i need to do any specific configuration settings on the PDA to enable detection by the WMDC specifically ?

Comment: If your question isn't about programming for these devices, which it seems like it's not, you're in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE provides support for different class profiles for USB client and when you configure your OS Design you may choose which of those profiles you want to support. If the manufacturer of your device did not include ActiveSync/serial (old name for WMDC) support in the image you can't sync your device.
If they did you may be able to change the device behaviour by changing the registry, as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms895481.aspx